# Ternjs package is making Sublime Text2 to hang in OS X

Tags: sublimetext2, osx-mavericks

I have to explicitly delete this TernJS package for SublimeText to work normally

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I couldn't use the "Package Control" to disable this package from within Sublime Text2. When I tried to it just hangs every after restarts. I previously deleted TernJs folder (step 2) and started the application without any issues. But whenever I opened Package Control the application will stop responding because it restores the deleted package. So I had to manually remove it from config as well.

1. Quit application first
2. I edited the "Package\ Control.sublime-settings" manually and removed TernJS.

   - $cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User/
   - $sudo vi Package\ Control.sublime-settings
   - Remove TernJs from the JSON settings `{
     "installed_packages":
     [
     .....
     "TernJs",
     ....
     ]
     }`
3. Deleted TernJs Package

   - $cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/
   - $rm -R TernJs
4. Opened Sublime Text2 without any issues